# Delegate touch events to parent with nested viewpagers

Tags: android, touch, android-viewpager

I have an app with nested viewpagers. The Top level viewpager is the ViewGroup of a tab layout and the child pager just swipes some images.

What I want to achive is that the inner ViewPager does completely delegate the touch events to the parent viewpager. I only want to scroll it's content with buttons.

To do so, I've created a Subclass for the inner ViewPagers:

```
public class NonTouchViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonTouchViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonTouchViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it only delegates the touch event if the inner ViewPager is on one of it's edges.
So if the ViewPager is on the left, I can swipe the parent pager to the left and if the inner one is on the right I can swipe the parent to the right. In any other cases the touch event is  just consumed and does not move the parent.

How can I achieve that the touch events are **always** delegated to the parent viewpager?

Thanks in advance,
McFarlane

Comment: Your current issue aside, do you think it's good design to nest ViewPagers? Wouldn't that be incredibly confusing and frustrating to the user?

Comment: @323go I do not see an issue in this. I'm doing the same thing. If you do not see the design, you can not judge over it...

Comment: Oh @Boy, I didn't "judge over" anything. I asked a question to get the OP thinking. And I've seen the design. It's iffy at best, not great UX -- but that's my *opinion* -- which is why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @323go Now I'm curious of the design ;)

Comment: @McFarlane did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @jzeferino not using view pagers. I did create an own view for our specific use case.

Comment: @McFarlane i'm having the same problema as you but i can't change to a custom view at this moment.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I found the solution. It was way simpler than i expected.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return false;
    }

}
```